# How to show files attached to Document with xp:fileDownload

Tags: xpages

In an application I have files attached directly to the Notes document and not to the document via a Rich text field.

I would like to make those files available in the xp:fileDownload control but that allows only file binding to a Rich text object.

> Binds the file control to a data element or other value which must be
>   of type rich text.
>   http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_controls_cref_filedownload.html

Is it possible to use the control somehow for making the files attached to the document available for download via this control?

Answer (score 0):

try to download the file using domino url api

```
<a href="database.nsf/0/documentUNID/$file/fileName.JPG">download</a>
```

[Domino URL](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Domino_URL_cheat_sheet/)

Comment: yes but then I miss some important features like icon display, date, filesize   as in the following image http://i.stack.imgur.com/E7amk.png